# Can I use Excel WEBSERVICE to scrape specific content from a page?

Tags: excel, web-services, web-scraping

I'm trying to import data from Yahoo Finance into a spreadsheet.

If I enter this in Excel...

=WEBSERVICE("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/")

...it returns a #VALUE! error because the content of the page exceeds the character limit for a single cell.

I only need the Yahoo Finance value listed after "Previous Close." Since this amount--presently 987.83--is well below the Excel cell character limit, is there a way to modify the function to return just that amount?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, `WEBSERIVCE` is used more along the lines of retrieving JSON or some sort of API endpoint. Your trying to parse an entire HTML page. So yes, you can use `WEBSERIVCE` to scrap content, but your specific page is returning too much data to handle.

Per the remarks [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEBSERVICE-function-0546a35a-ecc6-4739-aed7-c0b7ce1562c4):

> - If arguments result in a string that is not valid or that contains more than the allowable cell limit of 32767 characters, WEBSERVICE returns the #VALUE! error value.
> - If url is a string that contains more than the 2048 characters that are allowed for a GET request, WEBSERVICE returns the #VALUE! error value.

I would suggest using a traditional [Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-a-web-page-Power-Query-b2725d67-c9e8-43e6-a590-c0a175bd64d8#ID0EAAEAAA=2016)  where you can manipulate the webpage as desired.

And then you can grab the table as depicted below. Further more, this content will refresh dependent on the settings you allow:

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Thanks for this. I looked into Power Query--and replicated the steps in the link you provided--but this is just one of thousands of stocks for which I'd like to find the Previous Close price. Ideally I'd like to create a one column with stock names and another with Previous Close prices. Is Power Query suited to scraping one piece of data from thousands of pages? Or is it better for pulling lots of data from single pages--as in the example you included?

Comment: "One of thousands" - I think that's a job for VBA personally since that would be easiest for me. Otherwise you'll need to find a finance/stock API where endpoints are returned efficiently. I know there are free options out there that will give you an API key but can't vouch for real-time updates

Comment: Here is an example using `WEBSERVICE` as intended @user2258740 https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2013/03/21/use-webservice-functions-to-automatically-update-excel-2013-spreadsheets-with-online-data/

Comment: I've used WEBSERVICE with APIs before, so I know it works there. I was just wondering if it would work here as well. I'll try the VBA approach. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It very well can work in this circumstance without VBA @user2258740 As I mentioned you just need to find a quote company that provides free API access, or paid if you care that much, or any endpoint styled return that's more efficient than parsing an entire web page. I found an example [here](https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&interval=1min&apikey=demo) for MSFT symbol

Comment: I should have clarified this, but Yahoo is just one of the sites with which I'm working. So, I was looking for a single solution that would work on sites with or without APIs. In that regard, is VBA still your recommendation? Or would you suggest a different approach?

Comment: Ah. Well in that regard, it would be careless of me to provide any recommendation, since I don't know the scope of your project. I was just answering the question at hand. However, an API endpoint would eliminate web pages altogether, which I think would be easier, and the only variable you would have to change is the company symbol, then parse the results. APIs could be done with either WEBSERVICE or VBA, its personal preference at the end of the day. VBA could dynamically scrap nth webpages if you don't fancy the Query method.

Comment: I should have picked a non-API site to use as my example. So, that's my fault. In any event, this has given me some ideas to pursue. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I don't want to insult your intelligence, but I don't think you understand what API endpoints do. Your initial url was not an API site, it was just a web page that loads everything [pictures, graphics, audio, scripts, stylesheets, and even ads], where as API endpoints or JSON strips everything like that and only returns critical information in text format, like the MFST link I provided you in the above comment. Very resourceful and more efficient, and more importantly, works with `WEBSERVICE` Anyways, good luck! I admire your undertaking of Stocks :D

Comment: I didn't feel insulted. So, no worries. Also, I know the example I provided isn't an API itself. I meant I shouldn't have used a site that offered an API in my example. In any event, I think we're on the same page. And, I appreciate the help. Thanks again.